# DOJO Custom Dialog Box - does not parse template file

Tags: javascript, html, widget, dojo

I am new to DOJO. I have a custom widget , which uses a template file for the dialog box contents.
I am extending dijit.Dialog in the script file.

```
dojo.declare(
    "custom.credentials",
    [dijit._WidgetBase, dijit._Templated,dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin,**dijit.Dialog**],
    {


          templatePath: dojo.moduleUrl("custom", "templates/credentials.html"),
          ....
          ....
          postCreate: function() {

          this.inherited(arguments);
          alert(this.containerNode);
          alert(this.mainDIV);  
             },
          });
```

My Template test file looks like this

```
<div data-dojo-attach-point="mainDIV">
    Login Dialog Box template here
</div>
```

For some reason, when I alert on **this.mainDIV**, I get 'undefined'. It does not read the template file. Also, this.containerNode gives me 'HTMLDIVElement', (parent dijit dialog DIV).

I am not able to figure out after a lot of trial error where exactly the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Calling code**

```
function opnPop(){
var pop= dijit.byId("customPopup");
    pop.show();
}

<div dojoType="custom.credentials" id="customPopup"/>
```

**Note :** **When dijit.Dialog is **not** extended** it reads the template file without any problem, I.e, I am able to access this.mainDIV.innerHTML , that contains my own inner html contents.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Dialog has to be sub-classed, then it must be the base class. Here, it seems that it is used as a mixin. Anyways, the problem is with the template that is used. 
The template will be parsed and used by the code in Dialog. So, the template mentioned here has nothing but a div element with an attach point. There is no "**containerNode**" element (ie. attach point) and you are trying to access it in your js code, which will give error.

More important, the "**titleBar**" & "**titleNode**" elements are also missing form template, which will give errors while parsing the template. In order to avoid that, the code part that uses these elements need to be removed from js, to avoid error. So the widget creation will be successful. Try with the standard dijit.Dialog's template.
Add the `data-dojo-attach-point="mainDIV"` to the top level Dialog's div in the template.
In template, more things can be added, which won't cause any issues. But, if removed anything, will cause problem. If we are sub-classing a class/widget, we need to comply to the existing code.

Comment: Hi Vivek. I copy pasted the dijit Dialog template and added my custom markup inside it. Tt worked! Thank you :)